# Why does OIDC login breaks in Edge but not in FireFox?

Tags: firefox, microsoft-edge, openid-connect, .net-framework-version

I am wokring on a website (.NET Framework 4.6.1) and we implemented OIDC authentication (IdentityServer4). The implementation is very basic, nothing fancy just some code challange and token validation. We tested it and it worked real nice on both Edge and FireFox.

Then we were asked to implement "acr_values" parameter for MFA. In the authentication configuration, specifically inside `RedirectToIdentityProvider` (which is part of `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`), we add the specified "acr_values" parameter the following way (the value itself is set in a config file, and its similar to "xyz:asd:wtf:qwe"):

```
n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = authCfg.AcrValues
```

In a very similar setup (by similar i mean almost identical) it is working without any issues. For my setup it only works in Firefox. When trying in Edge we get `AuthenticationFailed` (which is also a `Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications`) with the following error:

> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup
> OIDC-Notification: AuthenticationFailed:
>
> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup Value cannot
> be null. Parameter name: s
>
> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup
> -TargetSite-------------------------------
>
> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup Byte[]
> FromBase64String(System.String)
>
> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup
> -Source-----------------------------------
>
> 2021-05-26 13:00:08.0633 ERROR MT.Translate.Startup mscorlib

In development enviroment the behaviour is a bit different. We do not get `AuthenticationFailed`, because after verifying the login information IdentityServer's redirection does nothing, but return us to the same login screen.

To summerize, without "acr:values" MFA was not working, but otherwise it was working in both Edge and Firefox. After implementig "acr_values" Firefox was working with MFA but not in Edge. So we rolled back to the previous version, where we have no "acr_values" and now MFA works with Edge and Firefox too.

The error does not make any sense to me. There is no parameter called "s", at least I have never heard of it in the context of authentication. The fact that without the necessary code it works does not make any sense to me. Also how can it work on Firefox and not on Edge?

Bonus Objective: Only in Edge a png is not appearing. It was not touched and in every other browser it shows up. How and why is my question.

Thank you for reading my post and I am looking forward to any insight what is happening.

Some code snippets:

```
oicdAuthOpt.Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                RedirectToIdentityProvider = n =>
                {
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Authentication && AppSettingsKey.AuthCodeChallangeEnabled.Enabled)
                    {
                        // generate code verifier and code challenge
                        var codeVerifier = CryptoRandom.CreateUniqueId(32);

                        string codeChallenge;
                        using (var sha256 = SHA256.Create())
                        {
                            var challengeBytes = sha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(codeVerifier));
                            codeChallenge = Base64UrlEncoder.Encode(challengeBytes);
                        }

                        // set code_challenge parameter on authorization request
                        n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("code_challenge", codeChallenge);
                        n.ProtocolMessage.Parameters.Add("code_challenge_method", "S256");

                        if (AppSettingsKey.MultiFactorAuthEnabled.Enabled)
                            n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues = authCfg.AcrValues ?? n.ProtocolMessage.AcrValues;

                        // remember code verifier in cookie (adapted from OWIN nonce cookie)
                        // see: https://github.com/scottbrady91/Blog-Example-Classes/blob/master/AspNetFrameworkPkce/ScottBrady91.BlogExampleCode.AspNetPkce/Startup.cs#L85
                        RememberCodeVerifier(n, codeVerifier);
                    }
                    logger.Debug("OIDC-Notification: RedirectToIdentityProvider Called");

                    //if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                    if (n.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout)
                    {
                        logger.Debug("  RequestType=" + OpenIdConnectRequestType.Logout);
                        var idTokenHint = n.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                        if (idTokenHint != null)
                        {
                            logger.Debug("  IdTokenHint got from n.OwinContext.Authentication.User");
                            n.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                        }
                        logger.Debug("  IdTokenHint=" + n?.ProtocolMessage?.IdTokenHint);
                        
                    }
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                },
```

Code for the IndentityServer is on their github ([Quickstart](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4.Quickstart.UI)).
For authorization middleware we made a custom `System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute`.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
        {
            try
            {
                if (AppSettingsKey.LoginEnabled.Enabled && AppSettingsKey.OpenIdConnectSSOEnabled.Enabled)
                {
                    var cookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["oidc.default"];
                    if (cookie == null)
                    {
                        logger.Debug("oidc.default is null -> HandleUnauthorizedRequest");
                        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
                    }
                    else
                    {

                        if (CookieKeyStore.Instance.CheckIfContains(cookie.Value))
                        {
                            if (!CookieKeyStore.Instance.isExpired(cookie.Value))
                            {
                                logger.Debug("oidc.default is not expired:" + cookie.Value + " -> OnAuthorization");
                                //requires oidc.default and ASP.NET_SessionID cookies
                                base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                logger.Debug("oidc.default is expired:" + cookie.Value + " -> HandleUnauthorizedRequest");
                                base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            logger.Debug("insert oidc.default into the KeyStore:" + cookie.Value + " -> OnAuthorization");
                            CookieKeyStore.Instance.HandleCookies(cookie);
                            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
                        }
                    }

                }
                else
                    base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                logger.Error(e, "Exception while overriding the OnAuthorization method.");
            }
        }
```

"oidc.default" is our custom cookie configured into OIDC.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            CookieName = "oidc.default",
            CookieManager = new Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.SystemWebChunkingCookieManager(),
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                OnResponseSignOut = context =>
                {
                    CookieKeyStore.Instance.Clear(context.Request.Cookies["oidc.default"]);
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Have you tried in Chrome to see if it works? Which version of Edge are you using? You say *In a very similar setup it is working without any issues*, you can compare it with your setup to find the difference and check if the difference leads to the issue. Besides, could you please provide [a minimal code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) which can **reproduce the issue** so that we can have a test?

Comment: @YuZhou Chrome did not work either, but the goal is to make it work on Edge. It was the latest Edge. We compared but there wasnt any significant change. I uploaded some code. These are the ones mostly touched in the issue, if you need more i will provide